# Hamilton cycle with mimimum possible maximum weight , approximation algorithm

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms, proof-writing

Let as assume that we have a complete , non directed graph $G(V,E,l)$. Each edge $e$ has a weight $l(e)\ge 0$ . We assume that the triangle inequality applies for all weights of edges .

How can I prove that there is no algorithm with approximation ratio smaller that 2, that finds a Hamilton cycle with the minimum possible maximum weight?

Comment: Cross-posted: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2238470/14578, https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/74089/755, http://stackoverflow.com/q/43441190/781723.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068). Each community should have an honest shot at answering without anybody's time being wasted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know the answer to the question you actually asked, you get a million dollars.

However, you can prove that it's NP-hard to find such an approximation algorithm, by reducing the problem to another NP-hard problem: the problem of checking if a general graph (not necessarily complete) has a Hamiltonian cycle or not.

Suppose that you have an algorithm which finds Hamiltonian cycles in a weighted complete graph whose maximum edge weight is within a $1.99$ factor of optimal. Given a graph $G$ on $n$ vertices that you want to test for Hamiltonian cycles, assign edge weights to the complete graph $K_n$ by

> giving each edge of $G$ weight $1$, and each non-edge of $G$ weight $1.995$. Note that this always satisfies the triangle inequality, since $1+1 > 1.995$.

If you can find a Hamilton cycle in the resulting graph whose maximum edge weight is within a $1.99$ factor of optimal, then that tells you if $G$ contained a Hamiltonian cycle:

> Being within a $1.99$ factor of optimal is the same as being optimal, here: if you got a $1.995$ maximum edge weight, and $1$ was possible, you're not within the margin. So if $G$ contains a Hamiltonian cycle, then traversing it gives a Hamiltonian cycle in $K_n$ with maximum edge weight $1$, and your algorithm has to find it.

Comment: Many thanks for answering this question ! ( Actually , thanks for all of your other answers.) May I ask one more related question?What happens if the triangle inequality is no longer satisfied in the above question?

Comment: The case where the triangle inequality holds is a special case, so if we can't even $1.99$-approximate the special case, we can't $1.99$-approximate the general case. But if you think about this proof, the triangle inequality was the reason we stopped at $2$, leaving the possibility that a $2$-approximation exists. For general weights that might not satisfy the triangle inequality, the same proof shows that no $100$-approximation algorithm exists, for any value of $100$.

Comment: Thanks for your precious help!